# Spring JPA dababase trigger JUnit testing

Tags: junit, spring-data, rollback, transactional, database-trigger

My case: Postgresql database, a 'spendings' table, a 'user' table with a 'total_spendings' column. I have a trigger on the 'spendings' table which updates the 'total_spendings' column.

I use Spring JPA and my test is annotated with

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@Rollback
```

After insertion on the 'spendings' table, I do not know how to retrieve the new value of the 'total_spendings' column. I reloaded the User entity and it shows the old value.

If I remove @Transactional and @Rollback, it works as expected, but I have to clean up the data after testing.

How to do this in a @Rollback unit test transaction?

Thank you

Comment: You could invoke `flush()`  on the `EntityManager` in your test class.

Answer (score 1):

As Davidxxx said you MUST execute flush() to force JPA to execute the SQL statements and this will execute the trigger.

```
// Inject the EnitityManager in your test class
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;


// Force JPA to execute the SQL statements
em.flush();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, thank you @davidxxx too. After I did that, I can see in the logs the insert statement gets flushed. The trigger runs, I tested by purposefully inserting an error inside the trigger function. However, the newly requested User is the same instance as the one I already loaded before spending insertion. I know that because the debugger shows the same User@11156. So I added entityManager.refresh(user) and all was ok

Comment: If you had more objects requiring refresh and wanted more powerful solution, instead of refreshing every entity it might be handy to call `entityManager.clear()` to clear the whole persistence context (just remember to do it **after** calling the `flush()`).